# What commonly used UIs suffer from commit messages over 50/72 chars per line?

Tags: git

After years of using git, I found that every single UI I've used for viewing commit messages is able to wrap long lines (50+ chars in summary line, or 75+ chars in details) nicely, so having these long lines had no consequences for me so far.

The UIs I've used are: various terminals, various IDEs and code editors, various git GUIs, and websites like Github.

What are some examples of UIs that are used by many people today, and can't wrap long commit messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any editor that doesn't support file type-specific formatting or doesn't have formatting specific to Git will suffer from this problem.  `nano`, Notepad++, and pluma are examples of the latter, and `nvi` (as well as most other non-Vim `vi` implementations) is an example of the former.

In general, there are just a lot of tools that view commit messages as plain text and don't bother to set specific settings for them.  Granted, most of the major IDEs and the typical common, powerful text editors do, but there's a long tail of options that people use.  Enumerating them all here is not possible.

The Git project uses an `.editorconfig` file to set text lengths for the `COMMIT_EDITMSG` file so that folks who don't have a suitably capable editor but do have one that understands EditorConfig files can be helped to do the right thing.